# Angular2 routerLink on hyperlink - {outlets:{}} has to be the last command

Tags: angular2-routing

Just upgraded to latest angular2 version - however I am unable to just supply a normal  link as per below:

```
<a [routerLink]="/home">Click it</a>
```

or

```
<a routerLink="/home">Click it</a>
```

The error is:

```
{outlets:{}} has to be the last command
```

I don't have a need for outlets, so just want to allow for a basic normal link - changing the hyperlink to a `<button>` works fine, it just seems to be on the hyperlink element.

I have not been able to find anything online with someone experiencing the same issue.

It was an existing project that was upgraded to latest angular, however I have a 2 others which went via the same process and they do not have this issue.

Any ideas?